# How can I query in sql to get a queryset reformated

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I have a user table whose primary key is `user_id` and an item table whose primary key is `item_id`.

Then I have another record table that records when a user picks an item (many to many). 
Its attributes include `user_id`, `item_id` and `pick_time`.

And I want to get a table like this:
[wanted query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxPUg.png)

in which "1" means that the user has at least once picked the item while blank means not.
Please help me with this problem in any case:

- How can I write my sql code to get this queryset?
- If can't solve this in a sql query, how to restructure my database?

Sorry for my bad sql skill and poor expression.

Thansk a lot!

Comment: Can you provide the details of user and item table please?

Comment: This is called a *pivot.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) in pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"Users": [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,5,1,2,4,5,2,3,4,5,4,5],
    "Items": 
['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','D','D','D','D','E','E']}

users_items_joined = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["Users", "Items"])
users_items_joined["count"] = 1
```

You will now have something similar to whats shown below,

```
    Users Items  count
0       1     A      1
1       2     A      1
2       3     A      1
3       4     A      1
4       5     A      1
5       1     B      1
6       2     B      1
7       5     B      1
8       1     C      1
9       2     C      1
10      4     C      1
11      5     C      1
12      2     D      1
13      3     D      1
14      4     D      1
15      5     D      1
16      4     E      1
17      5     E      1
```

You can also retrieve the actual table from database and convert it to a **pandas dataframe** and apply the below function on it to obtain the user item matrix you are expecting.

```
user_item_matrix = users_items_joined.pivot_table('count', 'Users', 'Items')
print(user_item_matrix)
```

This above code will give exactly what you have requested in the image you provided.

```
Items    A    B    C    D    E
Users                         
1      1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN  NaN
2      1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  NaN
3      1.0  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN
4      1.0  NaN  1.0  1.0  1.0
5      1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```